# Jsoup select different Div types and handle them sequentially

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

Hi I'm using `Jsoup` to scrape an html page, i have 2 `div` next to each other:

```
<div class="time_head">... </div>
<div class="blockfix">...  </div>
```

I need to to get the first `time_head`, and then put inside it.. all the elements from the first `blockfix`, and so on and so forth.

what i tried so far :

```
        Elements time_heads = doc.select("time_head");
        for (Element time_head : time_heads) {

            String the_time_head = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(time_head.getElementsByClass("time_head"))).text();
            Log.i("the_time_head ", " Hz:  "+the_time_head);
        }

        Elements blockfixs = doc.select("blockfix");
        for (Element blockfix : blockfixs) {

            String the_blockfix = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(time_head.getElementsByClass("blockfix"))).text();
            Log.i("the_blockfix ", " Hz:  "+the_blockfix);
        }
```

i need the result to be like:

```
      time_head1:
           ---- blockfix elemts1
           ---- blockfix elemts2
           ---- blockfix elemts3
      time_head2:
           ---- blockfix elemts1
           ---- blockfix elemts2
           ---- blockfix elemts3
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you post example with actual input and expected output?

Comment: i have updated my question with the output.. the input  2 div next to each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to iterate over all `div` elements which have either `time_head` or `blockfix` and depending on what you found print it differently. In that case you can use `select(CSSquery)` with query like `elementA, elementB` because `,` can be treated as OR operator here in CSS. Then depending on class name of currently iterated element chose how to handle it.

Demo:

```
String html = 
          "<div class='time_head'>time_head content1</div>"
        + "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix1</div>"
        + "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix2</div>"
        + "<div class='time_head'>time_head content2</div>"
        + "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix3</div>"
        + "<div class='blockfix'>blockfix4</div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for (Element el : doc.select("div.time_head, div.blockfix")) {

    if (el.className().equalsIgnoreCase("time_head")) {
        //handle time_head here
        System.out.println(el.text().toUpperCase());
    }

    if (el.className().equalsIgnoreCase("blockfix")) {
        //handle blockfix here
        System.out.println("----"+el.text());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TIME_HEAD CONTENT1
----blockfix1
----blockfix2
TIME_HEAD CONTENT2
----blockfix3
----blockfix4
```

Comment: this is what i need, thank you.. just  for clarification there is one div `blockfix ` after `time_head `, and inside `blockfix ` there is many div's.. should i do the same approach ?

Comment: please @Pshemo.

Comment: Answer depends on what you want to do and structure of those inner elements. Since I don't really know what your goal (involving those inner elements) is I can't really help you. BTW if it will invalidate already posted answer then instead of providing clarifications here consider asking it in [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you will provide all important details about HTML structure and problem which you are facing.